# SnowballStemmer for Russian words list

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming, snowball

I do know how to perform SnowballStemmer on a single word (in my case, on russian one). Doing the next things:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer 

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("russian") 
stemmer.stem("Василий")
'Васил'
```

How can I do the following if I have a list of words like ['Василий', 'Геннадий', 'Виталий']?

My approach using for loop seems to be not working :(

```
l=[stemmer.stem(word) for word in l]
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Using Python 3, I got this: `['васил', 'геннад', 'витал']`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your variable `l` is not pre-defined, causing the name error. See my last two lines for fix.

```
>>> from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
>>> stemmer = SnowballStemmer("russian") 
>>> my_words = ['Василий', 'Геннадий', 'Виталий']
>>> l=[stemmer.stem(word) for word in l]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'l' is not defined
>>> l=[stemmer.stem(word) for word in my_words]
>>> l
['васил', 'геннад', 'витал']
```